# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj when parsing nested JSON

Tags: jquery

I'm parsing the response of [this web service](http://smart-api.info/api/suggestion/?field=services.inputParameter.parameterDataType) to use the values of `key` as autocomplete suggestions. I'm able to get the values of interest, e.g. `VariantType`, but I am getting an error in the console:

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj"

How to resolve it?

Here is the code:

```
$( "#inputParam" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          // Suggestion API from smartAPI project, example input 'affy' return should display 'ids:affymetrix.id'
          url: "http://smart-api.info/api/suggestion/?field=services.inputParameter.parameterDataType",
          //url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
          dataType: "json", //Use jsonp for http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data ); // Works for http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity
            console.log(data)

            // Iterate through JSON object  
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {    //element is 'field_values' from JSON response
              console.log("Loop 1")
              $.each(element, function(key, value) {  //key is 'buckets'
                console.log("Loop 2")
                  $.each(value, function(k, v) {      // v is 'Object { key:"VariantType", doc_count=1}'' 
                    $('body').append($('<div>', {
                        text: v.key
                      }));
                  });
              });
            });
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message and point out which line in your code is triggering it?

Comment: your code is working.http://plnkr.co/edit/RHhuANbCPJfytvOwdpMW?p=preview

Comment: I think the  invalid 'in' operand obj"  error at different location

Comment: Possibly missing JSON.parse on the data returned.  So "dataParsed = JSON.parse(data)" ... then do an 'each' on dataParsed.  That missing step was what generated this error in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second loop

```
$.each(element, function(key, value)
```

will try to apply `each` to `doc_count_error_upper_bound` and `sum_other_doc_count` properties, which are neither objects nor arrays.

What is the need to use `$.each` to get these values? It is iterating through the whole array, through all objects of different types. You can directly iterate through the target array like this:

```
var arr = data.field_values.buckets; 
// Here, do something with arr
```

**What about Autocomplete**

It expects **an array of strings**, while you are passing **a custom object**. You need to convert your object to the array of keys. You can use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
$("#inputParam").autocomplete({
    source : function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://smart-api.info/api/suggestion/?field=services.inputParameter.parameterDataType",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function (data) {
                var dataKeys = data.field_values.buckets.map(function (x) {
                    return x.key;
                });
                response(dataKeys);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Here is the working demo snippet:**

```js
$("#inputParam").autocomplete({
  source : function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url : "http://smart-api.info/api/suggestion/?field=services.inputParameter.parameterDataType",
      dataType : "json",
      success : function (data) {
        var dataKeys = data.field_values.buckets.map(function (x) {
          return x.key;
        });
        console.log(dataKeys);
        response(dataKeys);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inputParam"/>
```